# Draft JS linkify/mentions plugin on convertToRaw removes anchor tag

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I am using the draft js editor and its linkify and mentions plugin.
Adding link and mentions with link work fine on editor but when I try to get the html, anchor tags are removed from the content.

My editor rendor

```
return (
    <div
      className={editorStyles.editor}
      style={{ height: '150px', padding: '10px' }}
      onClick={() => {
        ref.current.focus();
      }}>
      <Editor
        editorKey={'editor'}
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={onChange}
        plugins={plugins}
        placeholder={"What's on your mind"}
        ref={ref}
      />
      <MentionSuggestions
        open={open}
        onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
        suggestions={mentions}
        onSearchChange={onSearchChange}
        onAddMention={(e) => {
         
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

This is how I am trying to get the HTML

`draftToHtml(convertToRaw(_editorState.getCurrentContent()));`

If the editor has a link say google.com, the above code returns the plain text instead of the anchor tag though it shows the anchor tag in the editor. Same for the mention, I am adding the link for the mention, but there as well anchor tag getting removed.
If I copy paste a link say [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), then this anchor tag isn't removed.

How to get these html with anchor tags for linkify and mentions? Need help. I am not a pro here.

**Edit 1:**
I further checked and found out

1. Linkify on convertToRaw returns as plain text
2. Mentions works fine for convertToRaw, but draftToHtml not working here as its not supported.

I will have to manipulate the Raw data to achieve necessary result.

Answer (score 0):

The rendered link is part of the mention/linkify component and not part of the text. That's why it is missing in the export.

If you want to have the links in the output from `draftToHtml` you need to use the `customEntityTransform` parameter.

As from the [documentation](https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-to-html):

> `customEntityTransform` can be used for transformation of a custom entity block to html. If present its call to generate html for entity. It can take 2 parameter:
>
> - `entity` ( object with { type, mutalibity, data})
> - `text` text present in the block.